# Put null byte at the end of C array

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, undefined-behavior, null-terminated

I have seen this coding pattern multiple times when I am reading the source code of different projects.

```
z = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
buf[z] = 0;
```

As far as I know, this is to make sure the c-style string is correctly terminated by a null byte. But is this a good coding style? It looks like there is a potential out-of-bound write that may corrupt other data.

Comment: Yep, looks illegal to me. It should use `sizeof(buf) - 1`.

Comment: There are two questions: (1) is there room in the buffer for the `\0` and (2) do you need it at all?  Yes, the code you've posted fails to leave room for it.  But in most (though not all) cases where `read()` or `fread()` is being used, the code is dealing with counted arrays of characters, *not* true null-terminated strings, so an explicit `\0` terminator is unnecessary.  I suspect there's lots of code that appends it as a "cargo cult" technique, not because it's actually necessary.

Comment: To be really pedantic about good style, `buf[z] = '\0';` would more clearly show the intent of nul-terminating a string.

Comment: (continuing my previous comment) Only if you're later doing something like `strlen(buf)` or `printf("%s\n", buf)` do you need that `\0`.  But usually (though not always), `read` and `fread` are used to read binary data, meaning that it's probably meaningless to print the data as a string, or call `strlen` on it.  (Of course calling `strlen` is unnecessary anyway, because `z` already tells us that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I know, this is to make sure the c-style string is correctly terminated by a null byte.

Yes, that seems to be the most likely purpose.  Of course, that's only useful if one wants to interpret the data *as* a string.  That's not so uncommon, but it is by no means universal.

> But is this a good coding style? It looks like there is a potential out-of-bound write that may corrupt other data.

You are correct.  If the `read()` transfers the maximum number of bytes, and supposing that `buf` is defined as an array, not a pointer<sup>*</sup>, then the

> ```
> buf[z] = 0;
> ```

will perform an out-of-bounds access to array `buf`.  If one wants to be able to access the contents of `buf` as a string after the read, without losing any data, then one must reserve one character for the terminator:

```
z = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
```

Code that does not explicitly reserve at least one character in that way implicitly assumes that it will never see a maximum-length read.  That may be a relatively safe assumption in some cases, but it's not one I would want to hang my hat on.

Additionally, if the `read()` fails then it will return -1.  In that case, too, the assignment to `buf[z]` will be out of bounds.  That must be avoided by checking the return value of `read()` before using it, as one almost always should do with the return values of function calls that may indicate error conditions that way.

---

<sup>*</sup>If `buf` is a pointer rather than an array, then there is an altogether different problem: `sizeof(buf)` reports on the size of a pointer, not on the size of the object to which it points.

Answer (score 3):

`buf` must be big enough to hold the data plus the null terminator. The correct way is to read `sizeof(buf)-1` (assuming `buf` is type `char[]`) bytes to `buf`.

`buf[sizeof(buf)]` will access the memory *after* the last allocated member and is invalid because C arrays are 0 indexed.

The number returned by `read` is the number of bytes read or `-1` if `read` fails so be sure to check for this possibility.

The number of bytes read corresponds to the index in `buf` of the first byte not read.

**Correct code:**

```
z = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
if (z == -1) {
    // Handle error
} else {
    buf[z] = 0;
}
```

Comment: read(2) doesn't implement a null terminator so the -1 is not necessary.  The intent of read(2) is to read a sequence of bytes, not a string, so a null terminator would not make sense. See [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

Comment: @MikePelley I am not saying it does. The question is about reading bytes, and then adding a null terminator afterward.

Comment: Yes, I see I misunderstood your initial paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` function returns the number of bytes written to `buf`, if the call is successful. If an error occur the return value is -1.

So there is a possible out of bounds write both after the end of `buf` and before the start of `buf`.

One way of handling this is:

```
z = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
if(z >= 0) {
    buf[z] = 0;
} else {
    /* handle error */
}
```